# Have images change using Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have this assignment due tomorrow and Its to make an audio player in Flash using as3. I don't understand as3 at all. I have the code for the player working becuase I just used the same code we used in class, but I kind of want to make it my own.
I have created an Ipod style player. 
First thing, I want the Forward button to play the next song. How would I write the code for that?
Next When a song plays I want a specific image to show up. and when the next song comes on the next image to show

This is the code i have for the songs

```
function playTrack(e:MouseEvent) :void {
    switch(e.target.name) {
        case "track1":
            trackToLoad = "audio/Don't Stop Believing.mp3";
            trackName = "Journey • Don't Stop Believing"
            break;
        case "track2":
            trackToLoad = "audio/Never Never Land.mp3";
            trackName = "Metallica • Never Never Land"
            break;
    ...
```

but instead of having just a stop and play button and 10 buttons that play each song I want to have a skip button to go to the next song..

hope this is enough info for some help
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set your tracks up as an array of objects:

```
var track1:Object = {
  track: 'Don\'t stop believing',
  artist: 'Journey',
  file: 'dont_stop_believing.mp3'
};
var track2 //same as above
var tracks:Array = [track1, track2, ...];
```

You could really create a `Track` class, but it sounds like you aren't to that point yet.

Instead of making your `playTrack` function actually be the mouse event handler, you should separate it out so that it can be used universally no matter how the track begins to play (i.e. clicking on that track's button, clicking on the next button, or after the previous song ends).  Write a separate function just to handle the mouse event (i.e. `clickTrack()`), which will call your `playTrack()` function.

Setting your tracks up within the array will allow you to keep note of the indices of each track (including the `currentTrack`) as a number.  That way you can iterate through the tracks by just incrementing the `currentTrack` variable.

This way, you can set your `playTrack()` function up to take a `trackNumber` parameter (i.e. `playTrack(1)`.  Then just use that parameter to reference the index of the track you want to play within the `tracks` array.  Remember that arrays are on a 0 index meaning that the first element is index [0], the second is [1], etc.  So you'll either have to write your `playTrack()` function in that way, or convert by subtracting 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing some kind of `Track` object in an indexed array. You can keep track of the index, and change it when the user clicks **skip** or **back**. The `Track` object could store the filepath, the track name, and the art that you want to display. When the index changes, grab the correct track from your array and update the player.

[Here is an example that actually uses song titles.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7edf)

Comment: I kept my answer somewhat unspecific since this is a school assignment. Show progress for a more specific response. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, None of that makes any sense to me.